# Sub Query is too slow when select top 1 record for each parent

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

I am trying to locate the last record within the selected date using the sub query method. The problem is the query is too slow. I am wondering if anyone have any ideas on how to rewrite this query to improve the performance. My server is dying because of this.
To make it easier for testing I have created a table variable to generate fake data for testing purposes. To test this script please run usp_ExtractData'400000'

My concern is at ---SECTION B 
My result was 18 seconds for 400000*3 = 1200000 records. On the real database i do index it and re-index nightly.

```
--Store proceedure with table variable data

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ExtractData](
@TotalRecord int--Create random records for each product
)

AS
BEGIN
    --MS SQL 2008
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --SECTION 1--Create test data--- GO TO SECTION 2
        --Create Variable table to Products fake data
        DECLARE @Product TABLE
        (
          ProductID int primary  key not null
          ,SKU varchar(100) not null
        )
        --Insert couple records into @Product table
        INSERT INTO @Product(ProductID, SKU) VALUES     (100,'CUP100')
        INSERT INTO @Product(ProductID, SKU) VALUES     (101,'CUP101')
        INSERT INTO @Product(ProductID, SKU) VALUES     (102,'MUG101')

        --Create Variable table to hold Products History data
        DECLARE @History TABLE
        (
           ID int identity not null
          ,ProductID int not null
          ,VisitedDatetime datetime not null
        )

        --Generate random record for testing
        WHILE @TotalRecord>0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO  @History( ProductID, VisitedDatetime) VALUES (100,DATEADD(minute,rand()*100,GETDATE()))
                INSERT INTO  @History( ProductID, VisitedDatetime) VALUES (101,DATEADD(minute,rand()*100,GETDATE()))
                INSERT INTO  @History( ProductID, VisitedDatetime) VALUES (102,DATEADD(minute,rand()*100,GETDATE()))
                set @TotalRecord=@TotalRecord-1
            END
    --SECTION 1--Finised creating test data



    ---SECTION B 

      --SELECTION B1- SEE DATA
      SELECT * FROM @History         ORDER BY ProductID, VisitedDatetime DESC
        --Run query to find the last visit per each ProductID

        --THIS IS TOO SLOW
        DECLARE @TestPerformanceDatetime datetime--Test performance
        SET @TestPerformanceDatetime= GETDATE()
        SELECT  *, (select top(1) VisitedDatetime FROM @History as t2 WHERE t2.ProductID=ProductID and VisitedDatetime BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE()+10 ORDER BY VisitedDatetime DESC) as LastVistiDate
        FROM     @Product

        --Display the performance
        SELECT  DATEDIFF(SECOND, @TestPerformanceDatetime,getdate()) AS TotalSeconds
    ---SECTION B - End
END
```

Comment: Yes, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Comment: Is there an index on the `History` table in production, e.g. a composite key with `ProductId` and `VisitedDateTime` descending?  That should help you `select max( VisitedDateTime ) from History where ProductId = Outer.ProductId`.

Comment: yes, we do have 2 indexes(ProductID and VisitedDateTime)  for the History and 1 index(ProductID) for Product table.  The GETDATE() is just for testing purpose.

Comment: I think we have a failure to communicate.  I'm suggesting a single index on `History` that contains two columns: `ProductId` and `VisitedDateTime` (desc).  There may be additional indexes, but that one will speed up the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cross apply` and `max()`.

```
select *
from @Product p
cross apply (
    select MAX(VisitedDatetime) LastVisitedDatetime
    from @History
    where VisitedDatetime BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE()+10
        and ProductID = p.ProductID
) h
```

Comment: the max really improve the speed

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 0 seconds with original version of this query, so I upped the number of random test records from 400,000 to 4,000,000.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ExtractData_test](
@TotalRecord int--Create random records for each product
)

AS
BEGIN
    --MS SQL 2008
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --SECTION 1--Create test data--- GO TO SECTION 2
        --Create Variable table to Products fake data
        DECLARE @Product TABLE
        (
          ProductID int primary  key not null
          ,SKU varchar(100) not null
        )
        --Insert couple records into @Product table
        INSERT INTO @Product(ProductID, SKU) VALUES     (100,'CUP100')
        INSERT INTO @Product(ProductID, SKU) VALUES     (101,'CUP101')
        INSERT INTO @Product(ProductID, SKU) VALUES     (102,'MUG101')

        --Create Variable table to hold Products History data
        DECLARE @History TABLE
        (
           ID int identity not null
          ,ProductID int not null
          ,VisitedDatetime datetime not null
        )

        --Generate random record for testing
        WHILE @TotalRecord>0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO  @History( ProductID, VisitedDatetime) VALUES (100,DATEADD(minute,rand()*100,GETDATE()))
                INSERT INTO  @History( ProductID, VisitedDatetime) VALUES (101,DATEADD(minute,rand()*100,GETDATE()))
                INSERT INTO  @History( ProductID, VisitedDatetime) VALUES (102,DATEADD(minute,rand()*100,GETDATE()))
                set @TotalRecord=@TotalRecord-1
            END
    --SECTION 1--Finised creating test data



    ---SECTION B 
        --Run query to find the last visit per each ProductID
        --THIS IS TOO SLOW
        DECLARE @TestPerformanceDatetime datetime--Test performance
        SET @TestPerformanceDatetime= GETDATE()
        SELECT  P.*, LastVisitDate.VisitedDatetime
        FROM     @Product P
        LEFT
        JOIN  (select top(1) T2.VisitedDatetime FROM @History as t2
               ORDER BY T2.VisitedDatetime DESC) as LastVisitDate
          ON  LastVisitDate.VisitedDatetime BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE()+10

        --Display the performance
        SELECT  DATEDIFF(SECOND, @TestPerformanceDatetime,getdate()) AS TotalSeconds
    ---SECTION B - End
END
```

[image: Proof]

Comment: The VisitedDatetime is wrong. It should be using the last date per each product ID.

Comment: Fixed,  the group by was outside the sub-query.  Now I get consistent results, and you can see that 4mil records with your query takes 111 seconds on my system, but my method takes only 9 seconds.  that is roughly a 12 fold increase in performance.

Answer (score 0):

On my notebook I'm seeing about 102,346 ms to generate the history, 5,120 ms for the first search and 643 ms for the second.  OTOH, it's BOINCing Rosetta@Home flat out at the same time.

```
declare @HistoryRecordsPerProduct int = 400000

set nocount on

-- drop table #Product
-- drop table #History

-- Create the test tables.

create table #Product
  ( ProductId Int primary key not null, SKU VarChar(100) not null )

insert into #Product ( ProductId, SKU ) values
  ( 100, 'CUP100' ), ( 101, 'CUP101' ), ( 102, 'MUG102' )

create table #History 
  ( Id Int identity not null, ProductId Int not null, VisitedDatetime DateTime not null )
-- EDIT: Note the following index on both columns. 
create index History_Product_VisitedDateTime on #History ( ProductId, VisitedDateTime desc )

-- Populate the history table.
declare @Start as DateTime = GetDate()

while @HistoryRecordsPerProduct > 0
  begin
  insert into #History ( ProductId, VisitedDatetime ) values ( 100, DateAdd( minute, rand() * 100, GetDate() ) ) 
  insert into #History ( ProductId, VisitedDatetime ) values ( 101, DateAdd( minute, rand() * 100, GetDate() ) ) 
  insert into #History ( ProductId, VisitedDatetime ) values ( 102, DateAdd( minute, rand() * 100, GetDate() ) ) 
  set @HistoryRecordsPerProduct = @HistoryRecordsPerProduct - 1 
  end 

select DateDiff( ms, @Start, GetDate() ) as 'Elapsed History Generation (ms)'

-- Query the data.
set @Start = GetDate()
declare @End as DateTime = @Start + 10 -- Days.

select @Start as [Start], @End as [End]

select ProductId, SKU,
  ( select Max( VisitedDateTime ) from #History where ProductId = #Product.ProductId and
    @Start <= VisitedDatetime and VisitedDatetime <= @End ) as VDT
  from #Product

select DateDiff( ms, @Start, GetDate() ) as 'Elapsed Search (ms)'

-- And again with the data cached.

set @Start = GetDate()
set @End = @Start + 10 -- Days.

select @Start as [Start], @End as [End]

select ProductId, SKU,
  ( select Max( VisitedDateTime ) from #History where ProductId = #Product.ProductId and
    @Start <= VisitedDatetime and VisitedDatetime <= @End ) as VDT
  from #Product

select DateDiff( ms, @Start, GetDate() ) as 'Elapsed Search (ms)'
```

Comment: thanks Haba. I would give you a thumb up but i don't have enough reputation. The Max is the answer. Thank you.